# Change a checkbox checked state from a useEffect hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-router, state, use-effect

The value of context.number is 1. I want to set the input checked value to true based off the context.number. So if context.number is 1, the checkbox is checked for Module 1, showing that Module 1 is completed. I can only change the input value from the onChange event though, so i assume i need a useEffect hook so it does it automatically when context.number changes?

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { AppContext } from "../context/AppContext";

export default function Menu() {

  const context = useContext(AppContext);

  //Determine the modules
  const modules = [
    {
      title: `Introduction`,
      subtitle: "Lesson 1",
    },
    {
      title: `Overview`,
      subtitle: "Lesson 2",
    }
  ];

  //Create a checked state for each module
  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(new Array(modules.length).fill(false));

  //Change checked value method
  const handleOnChange = (position) => {

    //map through checked states array, if position === mapped item index, flip the value
  const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) => (index === position ? 
  !item : item));

    //set that items state to the new value in the array
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
  };

  return (
    <>
        <div>
            {modules.map((module, index) => (
              <div className={styles.menuCard}>
                <Link key={index} to={`/Module/${index + 1}`}>
                  <h2>{module.title}</h2>
                  <p>{module.subtitle}</p>
                </Link>
                <input
                  id={`check${index}`}
                  type="checkbox"
                  onChange={() => handleOnChange(index)}
                  checked={checkedState[index]}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: The real solution was to move the following code into context and save the state in there.

Answer (score 0):

I put this is my context file and was able to get it to work. This is a poorly worded question I realize but found my answer none the less. useEffect wasn't the problem, it was that each checkbox was only saving local state so if i rendered another page the checkboxes went back to being unchecked.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
const AppContext = createContext();

function AppProvider(props) {

  //Determine the modules
  const modules = [
    {
      title: `Introduction`,
      subtitle: "Lesson 1",
    },
    {
      title: `Overview`,
      subtitle: "Lesson 2",
    }
  ];

  //set module number state
  const [number, setNumber] = useState();
  //Create a checked state for each module
  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(new Array(modules.length).fill(false));

  //change module number method
  function completionHandler(value) {
    setNumber(value);
  }

  //Change checked value method
  function handleChange(position) {
    const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) => (index == position ? !item : item));
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);
  }

  //export method and state value
  const value = {
    number: number,
    modules: modules,
    checkedState: checkedState,
    handleChange: handleChange,
    completionHandler: completionHandler,
  };

  return <AppContext.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</AppContext.Provider>;
}

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```